# Opinions and suggestions regarding malware sandboxes

Tags: malware, automation

I'm relatively new in the field of automatic malware analysis and I'd like to ask about hands-on opinions about sandboxes in the following aspects:

- extensibility of the product - adding your own modules, interfere in the analysis process, ease of the process inself.
- depth of report generation
- malware detection evasion and if it is possible to change this logic
- performance issues

Till now I've been able to check cuckoobox system and it looks quiet promissing. I'd be glad to heir someones opinion (from personal experience) about that product too.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [reverseengineering.se]. Opinion based questions and product reviews are generally not constructive. If you have a specific problem that you faced, then you can ask for solutions and suggestions about that. Stack Exchange differs from forums specifically because the platform is suited to objective oriented Q&As. See [about] and [faq] for more.

Comment: If you want to ask about the effectiveness of a *specific* software/tool/plugin for a *specific* task/area, then you are welcome to do so.